# Quick Excel Chart Reference Change

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

Hi I am new the site and have what I hope is a simple solution that I cannot figure out.

I have a workbook with 10 identical tabs with different data in each. I have made a new tab that references Tab 1 to graph the various data I have. I am looking at about 20 graphs, now I want to do the same graphical analysis on the 9 remaining tabs while creating 9 new tabs to do so.

The only way I can seem to do this to copy the graphs and then change the data source in each graph, which is taking hours. Is there something I am missing, or is there a macro out there that would make this a lot easier?

Thanks very much in advance for your answers.

Comment: These other 9 remaining CHARTS should use the same data in SHEET 1 or each of them will have its own data range located in new sheets?

Comment: I have 20 CHARTS for data in SHEET 1, which is located in SHEET 11. I have SHEETS 2-10 that need the same 20 CHARTS, which will be placed in SHEET 12-20

Comment: I would do it this way, without VBA... Select `Sheet1` & `Sheet11`, copy both 9 times. each new pair will keep appropriate relations  to each other. Copy (or cut/move) data from your current sheets 2-10 to new data sheets. I think its approx. 5 minutes of your work. Much faster than creating any macro :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to mess with dynamically adding charts before. Here's a slightly modified snippet you can mess with. Lets say your range is current sheet's A1:B20 for simplicity sake.

```
Sub AddChart()
Dim ws as worksheet
For each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        'ADD CHART. . .
        ws.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ws.Range("A1:B20")

        'this makes the chart a certain size, fitted to a cell range.
        Dim RngToCover As Range
        Dim ChtOb As ChartObject
        Set RngToCover = ws.Range("c4:f8") 'chart will be the size of c4:f8
        Set ChtOb = ActiveChart.Parent
        ChtOb.Height = RngToCover.Height ' resize
        ChtOb.Width = RngToCover.Width ' resize
        ChtOb.Top = RngToCover.Top ' reposition
        ChtOb.Left = RngToCover.Left ' reposition


    'random other stuff I did with labels etc.
    ws.Unprotect
        ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
        ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Age Statistics"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels
    ws.Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
            False, AllowSorting:=True

  'go to next worksheet
Next ws
```